# pg_query() seems to not execute queries in a loop

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm converting a site from MySQL to Postgres and have a really weird bug. This code worked as-is before I switched the RDBMS. In the following loop:

```
 foreach ($records as $record) {
    print "<li> <a href = 'article.php?doc={$record['docid']}'> {$record['title']} </a> by ";

  // Get list of authors and priorities
    $authors = queryDB($link, "SELECT userid FROM $authTable WHERE docid='{$record['docid']}' AND role='author' ORDER BY priority");

  // Print small version of author list
    printAuthors($authors, false);

  // Print (prettily) the status
    print ' (' . nameStatus($record['status']) . ") </li>\n";
  }
```

the FIRST query is fine. Subsequent calls don't work (pg_query returns false in the helper function, so it dies). The code for queryDB is the following:

```
function queryDB($link, $query) {

  $result = pg_query($link, $query) or die("Could not query db! Statement $query failed: " . pg_last_error($link));

 // Push each result into an array
  while( $line = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $retarray[] = $line;
  }
  pg_free_result($result);
  return $retarray;
}
```

The really strange part: when I copy the query and run it with `psql` (as the same user that PHP's connecting with) everything runs fine. OR if I copy the meat of queryDB into my loop in place of the function call, I get the correct result. So how is this wrapper causing bugs?

Thanks!

Comment: run `pg_last_error() ` and let us know the output.

Comment: Strangely, there is no output from `pg_last_error()` -- even after with `pg_set_error_verbosity($link, PGSQL_ERRORS_VERBOSE);`. Notice that my wrapper calls `pg_last_error` already; look at http://peano.colorado.edu/libermath/repositorium/?field=8 to see the output (as of 2010-12-02T1601 MST).

Comment: Why don't you use pg_fetch_all() ? No need for a while-loop.

Comment: Frank, thanks for the tip, but that doesn't affect the fact that my query isn't being run after the first iteration.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but should be a sufficient workaround. Why don't you fetch the results in `1` query instead of `n` queries? Should be a bit faster too.

Comment: Does your query (e.g. `$authTable`) contain any reserved keywords? Postgres makes some problems when using reserved names without espacing them.

Comment: Thank you, WoLpH and DrColossos. First, I'd love to make it one query but each time I'm getting the authors for a different document, which would add work to my script if I get all at once. Seems to me to be about six of one, half dozen of the other. As for reserved keywords, there are none; `$authTable` expands to the name of the table, nothing more; `$record['docid']` is an integer. When I run the exact query (with expansion) in `psql`, everything is fine. It's not the query that's the problem; somehow it has to do with the `foreach` loop and `queryDB` wrapper function.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that there was no error output due to having my `php.ini` misconfigured; after turning errors back on I started getting output, I got things like`18 is not a valid PostgreSQL link resource`. Changing my connect code to use `pg_pconnect()` (the *persistent* version) fixed this. (Found this idea [here](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=115754&postcount=5).)

Thanks to everyone who took a look and tried to help!